# Even after using closure, the object value is not updating

Tags: javascript

```
var repeatelem = function(elem, n){
            // returns an array with element elem repeated n times.
            var arr = [];
            for (var i=0; i<n; i++) {
              (function(newValue, index){
                                console.log(index)
                                Object.defineProperty(newValue, 'reasonId', {
                                    value:index,
                                    configurable:true
                                });
                              arr = arr.concat(elem);
                        }(elem, i))

            };
            return arr;
        };
        var res = repeatelem({a:1},3)
        console.log(res)
```

OUTPUT : 
[image: OUTPUT]

I was excepting the `reasonId` to be 0,1,2.
not sure, why there is a problem here even after using closures the value of `reasonId` set to last index value.

[Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/v0jeu1mI1ViuKGs5XFxb?p=preview)

Excepted :

```
[{a:1,'reasonId':0 }, {a:1,'reasonId':1 }, {a:1,'reasonId':2 }]
```

Comment: A closure won't clone an object. Objects are passed by reference. You are essentially re-assigning the same property to the same object.

Comment: in other words: all three "copies" are actually the same object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript variables that contain objects, really contain a reference to the object, so you're closure properly copies the value of `i`, but `elem` and `newValue` are the same object. No copying is done.

So when you run `arr.concat(elem)` (which I think you meant `arr.concat(newValue)`) you are concatenating the same object into your array repeatedly.

You need to make a copy of your object, before you append it to the array. 
See [How do I correctly clone a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/728360/772035) . The closure is also unnecessary in your case; that is usually used to solve issues when there is asynchronous code in the loop. You can simplify your code to:

```
var repeatelem = function(elem, n){
    // returns an array with element elem repeated n times.
    var arr = [];
    for (var i=0; i<n; i++) {
        var copy = Object.assign( {}, elem );
        Object.defineProperty( copy, 'reasonId', {
            value: i,
            configurable: true
        });
        arr.push( copy );
    }
    return arr;
};
```

Where [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) is being used to make a shallow copy. It is an ES6 function that can be [shimmed for this use-case](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign#Polyfill) . Be aware that this is only a shallow copy and if the elements can have objects in their own properties you probably want a deep copy instead, otherwise each element will share their child objects with each other, so when you modify one child, they all change.